# Browser accessing rails app on heroku gets stuck 'transferring' data on any requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a confused newbie coder who doesn't know how to even start debugging/fixing this.  Just hoping someone has run into something similar and can point me towards what to investigate.

I'm working on a rails 4 app that runs fine in development on my local machine, but when deployed to Heroku, even the smallest html/json requests take over a minute to complete.  Every request seems to follow the same pattern: the html/json that the app is supposed to send back comes back well within 1-2 seconds and renders on screen as expected, but then my browser (both Firefox 26 and Chrome 32) just sits there on 'transferring' mode, as if it's waiting for more data.  Firefox says 'transferring data from [heroku]' down the bottom, and Chrome's little circle just keeps spinning.  After another minute or so, I suppose either the browser gives up or Heroku cuts off the connection, and the browser finally decides that it's finished with the transfer.

Heroku logs show that the various html/assets/etc are being served in well under 200 ms, and as far as I can tell my app itself is running fine.

This happens for everything on my app, from the simplest flat text pages, to json requests both tiny and large, and obviously the 'main' complex app page. Since the app is a multiplayer card game, requests taking over a minute make it unworkable.

Funnily enough though, on Chrome on my Android phone, everything works fine.

I'm using thin as the webserver.  The more exotic gems I'm using are websocket-rails, railsy-backbone and rufus-scheduler.

My first thought was that maybe it's the websocket code, but removing that gem / not using that code didn't seem to help.  In any case, the websockets messaging code seems to work fine even when the normal http requests are stuck.

Any thoughts on where to start looking?  Let me know if more info would be useful.

Comment: It's probably a database issue -- are you using Heroku's `PGSQL` db's or your own? If it's your own, you may experience huge latency, whereas the PGSQL instances in Heroku seem to work very well

Comment: I'm using pg, or at least I hope that's what this bit in my gemfile's doing: 
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

Comment: Hmm okay - and your Heroku app has the PGSql "add-on" applied?

Comment: Under my app details, I've got something called 'Heroku Postgres :: Aqua' under a 'hobby-dev' plan.  Database seems to work fine, as I can create users / login / logout / do other things that require a database to work.

Comment: Ohh that's okay :) Can you post your JSON code? Perhaps a link to your app?

Comment: Sure, here it is on github - https://github.com/lanstro/poker, and on heroku - http://localhost:3000/tables/1.  A typical short json request from the app is https://chinese-poker.herokuapp.com/tables/1/status.json.  A longer json request is https://chinese-poker.herokuapp.com/tables/1/players_info.json.  From my machine, any pages on the app and all the json requests do the 'hang for 1+ minute' thing.

Comment: Oops I meant https://chinese-poker.herokuapp.com of course

Comment: What code renders those JSON pages? Looks like a LOT of data

Comment: external_info in the player model does the grunt work - https://github.com/lanstro/poker/blob/master/app/models/player.rb, and it's sent via https://github.com/lanstro/poker/blob/master/app/controllers/tables_controller.rb.  I chose to go with one big json dump every 2 minutes or so rather than a lot of little ones spread out.  As noted the little json requests as well as flat html are also slow, so I imagine it's a deeper issue than the json size.

Comment: Maybe the problem could be with your server -- every time you perform a request, it locks up the server until the request is completed. Heroku gets around this issue by offering multiple "dynos", which allow concurrent connections. If you only have 1 dyno, it may be that its processing capabilities are leading it to take a long time to load?

Comment: Sounds possible I guess?  Not sure how to go about diagnosing whether that's the problem or not.... Heroku logs show that for the big requests like that players_info one, it's still completing it in 14ms, so suggests that even if there was a lockup, it wasn't for long.  Any thoughts on debugging strategies?  Also thanks for taking a look.